# Web Content Filtering

Tags: router, web, content-management, webfilter, content-filter

I have recently bought a Cisco ASA 5505 for my small business, I was initially led to believe this device could do some limited website filtering that we would need. (one list of unrestricted, and a second for email only) Since it has come to my attention that it may not be able to do this what equipment or software will I need to make this happen?

Comment: I currently have 2 unmanaged Hp 2312 switches if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very lightweight solution is to utilize the services of http://www.opendns.com

If you want total control, and have a spare machine to use as a server, the combination of [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and [SquidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/) is a pretty versatile solution.

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.urlfilter.net/ with ipcop.org

more... http://virtualmachinez.blogspot.com/search/label/firewall